# schools: how are they tagged - with the same method all over the world?

Tags: openstreetmap, xml, linux, overpass-api

are all schools tagged in the same way?  or do some countries do use a specal tag-(system)?

**update: thanks** to the responders: what does this mean  https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=school

Typ

countl Objekte
all: 592 443
0.02%

[Node] Node 325 974
0.36%

[Way] Way 260 384
0.11%

[Relation] Relation 6 085
0.23%

end of **update: thanks**

we have the central ressource for the tag-system
[http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dschool](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aamenity%3Dschool)

> how can we evaluate that?
>
> This area should envelop the full grounds of the school including all
>   the buildings, sports facilities and grounds. For schools with
>   multiple sites the multipolygon relation can be used. Tag the element
>   with amenity=school and name=* for the name of school. Suggested
>   additional tags include:
>
> ```
> operator=* - Name of operator, often the local education authority.
> addr=* - Address details
> capacity=*, for the number of pupils taught at the school
> isced:level=*, for the educational level (proposed tags)
> fee=yes if the the school makes a direct charge for core services.
> religion=*, if the school is associated with a particular religion (also denomination=*)
> wikipedia=*, for a link to a Wikipedia article about the school
> website=*, for a link to the school's own website
>
>  Public-images-osm logo.svg building = school Convent School's Pippal.JPG Description A generic school building. Used on these
> ```
>
> elements may be used on nodes should not be used on ways may be used
>   on areas may be used on relations Useful combination
>
> ```
> name=*
> amenity=school
> amenity=college
> amenity=kindergarten
> See also
> building=university
> ```

How to map

> there is just one school building:  Map the outline of the area Area
>   of the building and  add the tags amenity=school and building=school.
>   Of course you can add name=* and address as well.

Well - i wonder how we can get a concrete and concise result if we do a request for all the schools in the world

```
<!--
This query looks for nodes, ways and relations 
with the given key/value combination.
Choose your region and hit the Run button above!
-->
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “building=school” -->
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="building" v="school"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="building" v="school"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="building" v="school"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

btw - this above code does not function - and this below also not. 
what is wrong here?

```
This query looks for nodes, ways and relations 
with the given key/value combination.
Choose your region and hit the Run button above!
-->
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “building=school” -->
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="building" v="school"/>
      <bbox-query {51.5557914,0.2118915,51.5673083,0.2369398}/>
    </query>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

can you help out!?

Comment: Please don't do crossposts: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34206/gathering-the-information-of-schools-with-overpass-api

Comment: thx for the comment - i do as adviced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is IMHO simple and complex at once :)

In general most mappers will just use amenity=school as it's well documented and easy to find. But as OSM models get more and more detailed, some local mappers will look for more detailed tags instead (amenity=college, ..) and append more details. Also at some places the school areas might be tagged and not just the school building(s) that might be within this area. Also think about schools that have different localities spread over a city etc.
Also other parts of education might be mapped just as school: driving-, diving-, music-, language-, adult-highschool, ... so the dataset might be a bit "dirty".

You will get a very good overview on the usage by using the OSM statistiscs before you crawl global data:
https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=amenity%3Dschool

P.S: Please paste the second question in a dedicated new answer to keep the replys focused.

Comment: hello  - again thanks for the answers. i added a few things in the threadstart can somebody explain what the additional things mean; 

update: thanks to the responders: what does this mean https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=school

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to understand the above mentioned statistic data: countl means that we have 592 443 schools in the osm-map? that are 0.02% of all nodes / relations etc

Comment: Yep [thats it](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=school). But please pay attention if you just look at the numbers. This counts all OSM objects, including micromapped stuff as benches, trees, ... So it might make sense just to do a relative compare to well defined categories as buildings or roadnetwork. See [wiki:statistics](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/stats)

Answer (score 4):

The thing here is that you have given the example of `amenity = school` tag, but you are actually querying `building = school`. It is normal for buildings inside school to be tagged as `building = yes`, hence the query will not return them.

In the second query, the format of bbox-query should be like below.

```
<bbox-query e="7.25" n="50.8" s="50.7" w="7.1"/>
```

You only need to type `amenity = school` in the overpass-turbo wizard to get the schools. If you want buildings, then the query might be complex. You should look at the oeerass-api [documentations](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) and post new question.